# How to convert js Map to object in typescript with Object.fromEntries

Tags: typescript

My goal is to convert a javascript Map to an object, using `Object.fromEntries()` [ts-playground-link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=13&ssc=1&pln=13&pc=29#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJysg3sgUMg5CEAc1AgC5kBnMKUEgbn0IQHsAbNqK2%2005oWQAHekiogArgFsARtGYBfXLnYhayBBgCycYcgC8yEBADuyXcIA8AawgBPNjDQYANMjgh7APgAUASmZVHT0AOmoIMF8AcmIyE2j3ACYABhTAlTUNLShLAEFqAHlZACsIBDBDZGKyitCYKDZpAFFweghqXxzLDNU2dU4IUK4SLpDhAprysECgA)

The code I have in my typescript playground, looks like this:

```js
interface Car { 
    engine: string;
    color: string;
    price: number;
}

const carMap = new Map<keyof Car, any>();
carMap.set('engine', 200);

const carMapAsObject = Object.fromEntries(carMap);
console.log(carMapAsObject); // --> {engine: 200}
```

`Object.fromEntries(carMap);` does not work in the typescript playground, here it gives the error: `Property 'fromEntries' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'.(2339)`.

On my local machine, the error I get is different (error 2345):

```
Argument of type 'Map<"engine" | "color" | "price", any>' is not assignable to parameter of type '[string, unknown][]'.
  Type 'Map<"engine" | "color" | "price", any>' is missing the following properties from type '[string, unknown][]': length, pop, push, concat, and 24 more.ts(2345)
```

Is this not supported by typescript yet, or how should I do this object conversion? When looking at the console, I can tell that the underlying javascript is executing just fine

Comment: Sorry, misread the documentation. Yes, it should accept a `Map`. Your TypeScript compiler options should either target `esnext`, or it should include the relevant ECMAScript library that contains the interface definition for `Object.fromEntries()`

Comment: Does not help with `exnext` in the playground for some reason?

Comment: The playground doesn't let you test _everything_, you'll need to set it up in a local project on your computer, or use a more comprehensive online editor that gives you more fine-tuned configuration options than a simple dropdown can provide.

Comment: Seems that TS didn't add Object.fromEntries until recently and you must use `target:es2019` (not listed in docs under --lib so not sure how) Also it's been problematic since then: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30934 what did you end up doing?